# How to change image for login button for OAuth windows live Id?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jquery

I have develop code for live Id OAuth in my system. I want to chang the image provided by windows live Id.

How can i change it.

More over, When I do login once, it will automatailly alert the login detail when it i load the page again. (F5) before i click on button.

What is the reason?

My code is.........

```
<div>
<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "myclientId",
    REDIRECT_URL = "myredirectURl";
    //WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
    WL.init({
        client_id: APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
        response_type: "token"
    });
    var scopesArr = ["wl.signin", "wl.postal_addresses", "wl.phone_numbers", "wl.emails"];
    WL.ui(
    {
        name: "signin",
        element: "signInButton",
        scope: scopesArr
    });



    function userContactInfo(sesion) {
        var postalAddresses, phoneNumbers, emailAddresses;
        WL.api(
    {
        path: "me",
        method: "GET"
    },

    function (response) {
        if (!response.error) {
            alert('hello name:' + response.first_name);
            alert('hello email:' + response.emails['preferred']);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login.aspx/SaveFacebookAutoSignUp",
                data: "{ 'Name':'" + name + "', 'EmailId':'" + email + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("You have successfully sign in.Please Wait, we redirect you in a second.");
                    alert(data);

                }

            });
        }
    });
    }


    function onLogin() {
        var session = WL.getSession();
        if (session) {
            userContactInfo(session);
        }
    }

    function onLogin1() {
        WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
        var session = WL.getSession();
        if (session) {
            userContactInfo(session);

        }
    }

</script>
<div id="signInButton">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for call the sigin with a button, after, you can add the image you want, hope this help:

```
<body>
    <input id="login" type="image" src="Images/Image.png" onclick="login();"/>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "xxxx",
        REDIRECT_URL = "xxxx";

        WL.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = (e.status === "connected" ? "Sign out" : "Connect");
        });
        WL.init({
            client_id: APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID,
            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL
        });

        function login() {
            if (WL.getSession() === null)
                WL.login({ scope: "wl.signin" });
            else
                WL.logout();
        }

    </script>
```